# C++ Error :Unhandled exception : Access violation reading location

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, unhandled-exception

I am doing testing and below is a piece of code that is giving me an error : Unhandled exception at 0x00956faa in myprogram.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcccccccc.

The function is:

```
ECommand(unsigned char CBuffer[], const CDBuffer_t * const SdBuffer_Ptr)
```

The piece of code:

```
unsigned char CBuffer[11];
memset(CBuffer,0,sizeof(uint8_t)*4);
CBuffer[2] = 0x02;
CDBuffer_t sendBuffer;
sdBuffer.buffer = static_cast<uint8_t *>(malloc(sizeof(uint8_t)*8));
memset(sdBuffer.buffer,0,sizeof(uint8_t)*8);
CBuffer[6] = 0x02;
ECommand(CBuffer,&sdBuffer);
```

getting error at:

```
ECommand(CBuffer,&sdBuffer);
```

Also

```
typedef struct CDBuffer_t
{
uint8_t *buffer; 
uint16_t count; 
uint16_t size; 
uint16_t status; 
} CDBuffer_t;
```

If any more info is required let me know. I know its something to do with memory accessing but am not able to figure it out
please help me get rid of the program crashing because of above exception
Thanks

Comment: This code looks more C than C++ (using `malloc` and not `new`).

Comment: @SurvivalMachine: you shouldn't use `new` in C++, either ;) Except for very few very special cases.

Comment: ya actually the main code is in c and for testing c++ is used

Comment: @VioletGiraffe true, I didn't say that `malloc` or `new` is needed here.

Comment: Impossible to say without knowing what `ECommand` requires of its parameters.

Comment: What more Info is required like ECommand whole function? or something from it @molbdnilo

Comment: @mentaalcoder Since you're testing, don't you have access to the developer of `ECommand` and can ask them if you're using it correctly, or at least its documentation? It's impossible for outsiders to guess whether the problem lies with the testing code or whether you have found a bug in `ECommand`. (That you're not initialising all of `sendBuffer` looks very fishy, though.)